# How can I use Table in a replacement rule?

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, rule, variable

I would like to implement the following replacement rule:

$$tr[a^k]^\ell \longrightarrow t[\underbrace{k,k,...,k}_{\ell\ \text{times}}]\,. \tag{1}$$

My (naive) attempt was to write:

```
tr[a^2]^5 /. tr[a^k_]^l_ -> t[Sequence @@ Table[k, {i, 1, l}]]
```

But this gives me the error message `Table: :iterb: Iterator {i,1,l} does not have appropriate bounds`, which means that the variable $\ell$ is not transmitted "on time" to the table. Another similar attempt was to use `ConstantArray[k, l]` instead of the table, but the problem seems to be the same (and the output is not correct).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed`, i.e., `tr[a^2]^5 /. tr[a^k_]^l_ :> t[Sequence @@ Table[k, {i, 1, l}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Amazing, thanks! I did not know what the function of `RuleDelayed` was. Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @BobHanlon in the comments, the solution is to use `RuleDelayed` in the following way:

```
tr[a^2]^5 /. tr[a^k_]^l_ :> t[Sequence @@ Table[k, {i, 1, l}]]
(* t[2,2,2,2,2] *)
```

This produces the desired output.

Comment: Or more succinctly `tr[a^2]^5 /. tr[a^k_]^l_ :> t @@ Table[k, {i, 1, l}]`